# Generics typeof <T> with Activator

Tags: c#, generics

I currently have to use a large class that has a common property name. The details within the sub class are the same (I am unable to change the class). Instead of adding the Amount class over again to different sections I would like to use generics and reflection to instantiate it.

I have the following code:

```
var amountProperty = value.GetType().GetProperty("Amount");
if (amountProperty != null && amountProperty.PropertyType.IsArray)
{
    Type amountTypeArray = amountProperty.PropertyType;
    Type amountType = amountProperty.PropertyType.GetElementType();

    var amountValue = amountProperty.GetValue(value);
    if (amountValue == null)
    {
        amountValue = Activator.CreateInstance(amountTypeArray);
    }
    else
    {
        amountValue = IncrementArray<amountType>(amountValue);
    }
}
```

The 3rd last line `amountValue = IncrementArray<amountType>(amountValue);` has an error on `amountType`. If I put it in `typeof(amountValue)` also doesn't work. The `incrementArray` method is:

```
protected T[] IncrementArray<T>(T[] arrayIncrement)
{
    var sectionCopy = arrayIncrement;
    Array.Resize<T>(ref sectionCopy, arrayIncrement.Length + 1);
    return sectionCopy;
}
```

I am probably just missing a real simple solution.

Comment: Generics and reflection do **not** make good friends. It can be *done*, but it is very expensive... not a great approach, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Reflection` to call `IncrementArray<T>` method.

First get the `MethodInfo` then use `MakeGenericMethod`

```
// Assuming incrementMethod is the MethodInfo of IncrementArray<T>
incrementMethod.MakeGenericMethod(amountType).Invoke(amountValue);
```